# HttpURLConnection: resulting json-code suggests page doesnt exist (404), even when url is correct

Tags: java, php, mysql, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get data from an MySQL database using a php-file. My java code is as follows:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(getURL);
        System.out.println(getURL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        //conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Append parameters to URL
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("user", USER);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("pass", PASS);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("server", SERVER);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("db", DB);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        // Open connection for sending data
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

        // Check if successful connection made
        if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            // Read data sent from server
            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            result = reader.readLine();
            return(result);

        }else{
            return("unsuccessful");
        }
```

When I go to my url (hidden in the variable getURL) using a browser, I see string of json on my screen, just as it should. However, when I output the contents of the reader (above code only takes the first line, but by adapting the code I can, of course, output more) it shows the html-code for a website displaying a 404 - Page does not exist message.

Anyone has any idea what goes wrong? Yes, I did check for typo's.

Comment: Maybe some redirect inbetween that you didn't notice while manually navigating to that page, but that breaks your request.

Comment: Where ius getURL defined?

Comment: getURL is defined in the class that this one is extending. Why?

Comment: @Xatenev: You may be onto something. When I use the URL in the browser, it removes the "http://" part of the URL. The problem is that when I do so in the code, I get a “java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found".

Comment: @MWB Just for your info, even if it works now: Almost all Browsers remove the http:// part - that has nothing to do with a redirect. The Protocol is only shown when your site is SSL protected (**HTTPS**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have no clue what happened, as I didn't change anything. But all of the sudden it started working?!?

Must have been something server-side I guess...

Thanks for the input and sharing your thoughts!